# How to specify more than 1 content type for a mule inbound endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, mime-types, mule, content-type

We use mule in which we deploy some of our services.

For one of our service, the input can either be application/xml or application/json. How can i specify multiple content types for the same inbound endpoint.

This is how we had it when we had just one content-type to deal with.

```
<https:inbound-endpoint address="https://localhost:43123/v1/cars"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" contentType="application/xml">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" />
        </https:inbound-endpoint>
```

how do I specify that the above inbound point should be able to handle content types of 'application/xml' and 'application/json'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contentType` attribute doesn't have any effect on *inbound* HTTP endpoints.

Just remove it and check the actual content type in the inbound property named `http.headers` with an expression like: `#[message.inboundProperties['http.headers']['Content-Type']]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does contentType have any effect on outbound HTTP endpoints?..how to handle the situation where there can be more than one content type for outbound endpoints. In my case, the outbound endpoint is a REST http endpoint which takes in json and xml

Comment: content-type attribute on the http:outbound tag has no much use. If you want to set content type on outbound http then try setting the "Content-Type" as a outbound property.